# Getting the current user's wallpaper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB.NET that needs to get the path to the current user's wallpaper. Does anybody know of a method that will do that?

Comment: I really hope not - also read this http://devcity.net/Articles/119/1/vb2005_wallpaper.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the current wallpaper from the registry. No need for any API calls whatsoever.
Here's the code to do that

```
Private Function GetCurrentWallpaper() As String
    ' The current wallpaper path is stored in the registry at HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper
    Dim rkWallPaper As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Desktop", False)
    Dim WallpaperPath As String = rkWallPaper.GetValue("WallPaper").ToString()
    rkWallPaper.Close()
    ' Return the current wallpaper path
    Return WallpaperPath
End Function
```

Comment: This will not work, if user has deleted the wallpaper after setting it

Comment: @automaticSoldier: Yes, you are right. That is an edge case that will need to be addressed by the developer. What I have provided here is a solution that works most of the time unless the user has been doing something _unusual_.

Answer (score 4):

I know that it's pretty late but for anyone else... If the desktop background(wallpaper) is a picture(not a solid color) you can find the current picture in the directory:

"C:\Users\ {username} \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\"

Answer (score 2):

You have to pinvoke SystemParametersInfo() with SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER.  That returns the path to the wallpaper bitmap file.  Visit pinvoke.net for the required declarations.

Comment: wow i knew about that function in C++ but had no idea that you could use it in VB.NET! Really complicated implementation though

Comment: Yup, the Visual Basic team members are no longer in the witness protection program.